# How to check that Typhoon assembly config contains value for some key?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, typhoon

I want to create unit test to ensure that assembly's config has correct value for some key.

Assembly declares it's config like this:

```
- (id)config
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition configDefinitionWithName:@"SomeConfigFile.plist"];
}
```

and sets some objects' properties like this:

```
[initializer injectParameterWith:TyphoonConfig(@"some.config.key")];
```

And I want to check that assembly does so with correct key, i. e. like this (pseudocode):

```
assertEquals([myAssembly configValueForKey:@"some.config.key"], @"correct key value");
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend that you create integration tests for your object, after it is emitted from Typhoon. One of these tests will be that the object is in the required initial state:

```
@implementation MyTestCase
{
    TyphoonBlockComponentFactory *_factory;
}

- (void)setUp
{    

    //Recommend putting this in a common place, so main test assembly only has to be set up once
    _factory = [[TyphoonBlockComponentFactory alloc] initWithAssemblies:@[
        [ApplicationAssembly assembly],
        [CoreComponents assembly],
        [PersistenceComponents assembly],
        [NetworkComponents assembly]
    ]];

    TyphoonConfigPostProcessor *postProcessor = [[TyphoonConfigPostProcessor alloc] init];
    [postProcessor useResourceWithName:@"Config.plist"];

    [factory attachPostProcessor:postProcessor];

}

//Assuming a classroom configured with a teacher count from Config.plist
- (void)test_classroom_should_initially_have_one_teacher
{
    CoreComponents *components = [factory asAssembly];
    ClassRoom *classRoom = [factory classroom]; 

    XCTAssertEquals(1, classroom.numberOfTeachers);

}
```

. . . from here you can go on and write other integration tests for your component.

**Integration Testing Guide:**

- Here's a guide about [integration testing in Typhoon](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Integration%20Testing).
- You could test the TyphoonConfig plumbing, but *testing the objects that get built by the assembly* focuses on requirements (BDD), and provides implicit coverage of all aspects of the assembly.

Comment: This looks like the least evil in my case. Actually I didn't want to add such a stub component into my assembly just for tests, but it's not big deal, in the end. Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: Answer was not suggesting a stub component, but the actual object, as part of testing the requirements.

Comment: I doubt it's good idea to expose actual object's configuration values

Comment: Not following you. Please raise a github issue if you feel something could be improved.